# CSS: using min-width and max-width for browser window auto-resizing?

Tags: css

It's the middle button in Windows and the green dot in OS X- that button that adjusts a window size for a web page.

I use min-width:1000px to define where to auto-size to when the window size is less than 1000px, and it works, except there's maybe 1em on either side of the page still showing.

Any ideas on what this can be and how I can fix it?

Comment: When you talk about the middle button in windows, do you mean the maximize/restore button in the title bar? It doesn't adjust the window to the webpage's characteristics.

Comment: The maximize button?... Maybe it's only Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CSS reset? If you have a small margin/padding/border showing on the edges of the page you can benefit from using a CSS reset at the top of your stylesheet like:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

As seen [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Or perhaps you are using one?

Comment: I'm not, but I tried that code out (thanks)... And it screwed up a bunch of elements, though the left side wasn't showing any background.